# problem with implementing stackoverflow-like tag search bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all, sorry for the weirdly phrased question. My problem is that when the tags overflow the container you can't see the search anymore and I want it to kind of move everything back in the search and slide the search forward like in the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A25RF.jpg

what's actually happening

https://gyazo.com/6c0e0064ad13d9fe4cfd6e05c20c72e8

My html code

```
 <div id = "home-search" class="searchbar">
    <span class = "taglist">
        <!-- these are just mvc tag helpers -->
        <Tag tag-text = "sql-server"></Tag>
        <Tag tag-text = "CSharp"></Tag>
        <Tag tag-text = "life-drawing"></Tag>
        <Tag tag-text = "game-dev"></Tag>
    </span>
    <span class = "searchbox"><input class = "" placeholder="Search..." name=""></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you so much, post your comment as an answer and i will gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how the new-question tag box works on SO, it looks like it sets the left-margin to a `-ve` amount when the it gets too big.

You already have a nice separate of input UI (the box) vs the tag container vs the actual input.

One way to implement this is to check the left position of `.searchbox` (relative within `.searchbar`) and if more than a certain amount (75% or 50%, or more exact 100px) then subtract that amount of the searchbar width from the left margin (using `px` may make this easier and more consistent).

Repeat each time the `.searchbox` becomes too far to the right.

You can check on `.input` or on completion of a tag, depending on requirements / how you like/prefer the feel.

Comment: oooh i seee. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event that transform what you type into a tag trigger, you can add this

```
var lastTagSize = $('tag','.taglist').last().width();
$('tag','.taglist').first().css('margin-left','-' + lastTagSize);
```

So I simply pickup the width of the new tag and sub it to the first tag left margin.